# How to look around a scene in first person in Three.JS?

Tags: three.js

I have rendered a simple cube in Three.JS to the screen, now the way I have found online is that I need to use PointerLockControls.js lock the mouse and look around the scene. I have managed to look the cursor and hide it using this, however I am unsure how I go about implementing "look around"

Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="javascript/three.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript/PointerLockControls.js"></script>
        <script>

            var scene, camera, renderer, geometry, material, cube;

        var init = function(){

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
            material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );

            camera.position.z = 5;


            document.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);

            //const controls = new PointerLockControls( camera, document.body);
            controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls( camera, document.body );


        }


function doMouseDown(event){
controls.lock();

}



            function render() {
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };


init();
render();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "looking around", I assume you want to move the camera around?
This may be a start for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
body { margin: 0; }
#js3canvas { width:800px; height:600px; }            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<canvas id="js3canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="javascript/three.js"></script>
    <script>
  var scene, camera, renderer, geometry, material, cube;
  var canvaselt = document.getElementById("js3canvas");
  var init = function(){
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, canvaselt.clientWidth/canvaselt.clientHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas:canvaselt } );
  renderer.setSize(canvaselt.clientWidth, canvaselt.clientHeight);
  geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
  cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( cube );
  camera.position.z = 5;
  canvaselt.addEventListener("mousemove", doMouseMove, false);
}
function doMouseMove(ev) { // point camera 
  camera.lookAt((ev.pageX-400)/100, -(ev.pageY-300)/100, 0);
}
function animate() { // need to animate, not just render once
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
init();
animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```